# Reconstruct spectral signal of light from an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi

im currently working on a project using the raspberry pi NoIR camera module. Basically what we want to do is: Make the infrared-spectrum visible for the human eye without just false-coloring it. 
We got the tip to estimate the original incoming light frequencies for every pixel and shift those into human spectrum. 
I need help understanding though, how to get that approximated function of the light when all i have is : the NoIR camera, a filter for just IR, a filter to block IR and the spectral response of the camera. ( Im trying to get into MatLab btw for this project)
Thank you for your help

Comment: Any visualization of light in the IR spectrum is false color by definition because IR is not in the visible spectrum. Are you asking how to choose a color map that preserves some characteristics of the sensor measurements?

Comment: who gave you that tip? some professor or teacher? I presume you are not supposed to just ask for a solution on stack overflow... you're sabotaging your own education...

Comment: well you got the data we don't .... what you should try is linearize your IR bands (reconstruct original spectra in the IR compensating IR response of your sensor) then extrapolate to visible frequency range. The result is of coarse far from reality without any additional info about the image content (light sources and objects physical and optical properties). How ever if you got just single IR band you can not do this at all ... with 2 you can use linear extrapolation and with 3 quadratic... assuming light spectra is continuous ...